# Unable to add mp4 video to hd to sd flow player script

Tags: javascript, flash, flowplayer

I want to use this flow player script : [sample](http://flash.flowplayer.org/demos/plugins/streaming/hdtoggle-httpstreaming.html)

i have 2 video one is sd ( X.mp4 ) and second one is hd ( X.hd.mp4 ) video

i want to same functionality but need only my video only.

bellow is my javascript code

`<script>`

flowplayer("httpstreaming-hd", "http://releases.flowplayer.org/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf", {
    plugins: {

```
    f4m: { url: "flowplayer.f4m-3.2.10.swf" },

    httpstreaming: { url: "flowplayer.httpstreaming-3.2.11.swf" },

    // the "tube" skin
    controls: { url: "flowplayer.controls-tube-3.2.16.swf"},
    bitrateselect: {
        url: "flowplayer.bitrateselect-3.2.14.swf",

        // show the HD button only in the controlbar
        hdButton: { place: 'controls'},

        // show the selected file in a content box
        // usually omitted in production
        onStreamSwitchBegin: function (newItem, currentItem) {
            $f("httpstreaming-hd").getPlugin('content').setHtml("Will switch to: " +
                newItem.streamName + " from " + currentItem.streamName);
        },
        onStreamSwitch: function (newItem) {
            $f("httpstreaming-hd").getPlugin('content').setHtml("Switched to: " +
                newItem.streamName);
        }
    },
    // a content box to display the selected bitrate
    // usually omitted in production
    content: {
        url: "flowplayer.content-3.2.9.swf",
        bottom: 30,
        left: 0,
        width: 420,
        height: 150,
        backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        backgroundGradient: 'none',
        border: 0,
        textDecoration: 'outline',
        style: {
            body: {
                fontSize: 14,
                fontFamily: 'Arial',
                textAlign: 'center',
                color: '#ffffff'
            }
        }
    }
},
clip: {
    url: "sample2.f4m",
    provider: 'httpstreaming',

    // we need 2 urlResolvers
    urlResolvers: ['f4m','bitrateselect'],

    // directory where the manifest and video fragments are stored
    baseUrl: "http://stream.flowplayer.org/httpstreaming/",

    autoPlay: false,

    // configuring the sd and hd properties is mandatory
    bitrates: [
        { url : 'video/vid.mp4' ,bitrate: 500, label: '500k', sd: true},
        {url : 'video/vid.hd.mp4' , bitrate: 1500, label: '1500k', hd: true}
    ]

} ,
playlist: {  'url': 'video/vid.mp4', 'provider': 'httpstreaming', 'main_video': true }
```

});

</script>


Thanks in advance.